# Google Adsense not working for rails root path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, adsense

I'm trying to add Google Adsense to a Rails 4.2 project. I have included the Ad code in the application.html.erb file and it mostly works fine.

However, it will not display on the root path when I push it live.

For example:

```
[https://]mydomain.com/posts/1 - Ad displays
[https://]mydomain.com/comments/index - Ad displays
[https://]mydomain.com - won't display the Ad under any circumstances
```

Its just for the root that the Ad won't display. The funny thing is that when I test the root at localhost, the Ad displays.

I have checked the settings on my adsense account and I can't find anything that precludes the root.

This is a forced ssl project. I have tried playing with turbolinks etc. I have tried different browsers etc. I think that there is some setting that I can't find on Googles' side...

Has this happened to anybody before?

Comment: Does your request actually hit Rails? Do you see it in log/production.log?

Comment: Yes. I think there must be something excluding the root on the adsense account settings (like a mydomain.com/*). But I can't find anything like this.

Comment: Try checking your robots.txt. It shouldn't contain "Disallow: /" line.

Comment: The robots.txt doesn't have the root disallowed. I appreciate your suggestion though